# Is there a way to combine observer.next and observer.complete when writing new Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

For example, in I use the following template a lot when creating new Observables:

```
myFunction(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
     // do things, like make HTTP calls, cache, etc.
     // generate valueToReturn
     observer.next(valueToReturn);
     observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this? I know about `Observable.of` but that's only if you need a short Observable without complex actions.

I know that you can just return an HTTP call.

Comment: where you are defining variable `observer`

Comment: @Aravind that's just Angular 2 syntax...

Comment: so what is that you are looking for?

Comment: What are these 'complex actions'? Usually you do Observable.of(...) and add any amount of actions to it with operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to combining the two lines, then: No, there is no such thing.

But just as a sidenote: The stream that you lined out with your comments seems like a pretty normal stream: Http -> map values -> return values and should not require an `Observable.create` - from using RxJS in multiple larger projects I can only recall 2 cases where an `Observable.create` was required, we were able to handle everything else by chaining the built-in rxjs-operators.

Here is a very simple example:

```
myFunction(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(someAddress)
        .map(data => data.json())
        .map(toClientSideUsableData)
        .do(data => this.myService.cache = data)
        .do(raiseAlertIfInvalid);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing more than just getting the data though. I'm also saving things to cache. Is that what the `.map(toClientSideUsableData)` is suppose to represent? I'm not familiar with what that's doing. Sometimes I'm not even returning data. I'm just assigning some data to memory on a service that a view will then render by calling the service. I'm just making sure that those data is loaded on a service before I push to a different view.

Comment: If you are saving data to a service you can use the .do-operator - the function will be executed when the data is received, no need for a custom observable - i'll edit my answer later

Comment: This is pretty cool stuff. Thanks for showing the `do` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 http does it by default. Look at the Angular source code [xhr_backend.js](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts)

```
       if (response.ok) {
          responseObserver.next(response);
          // TODO(gdi2290): defer complete if array buffer until done
          responseObserver.complete();
          return;
        }
```